# how to rename dataframe columns that match regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I'm trying to rename pandas dataframe columns that match a regular expression and leave others as they are.

I have multiple dataframes and some of them do not contain columns which match the regex at all.

For example:

```
#no matching columns
['Description', 'Image']
```

```
# 3 Matching columns
['Name (Ka)', 'Name (En)', Name('Ru'), 'Description', 'Image']
```

Here is my list comprehension and languages dict.

```
languages = {
    'ka' : 1,
    'en' : 2,
    'ru' : 3
}
```

```
#in case of non-matching dataframe this comprehensions raises "ValueError Length mismatch: Expected #axis has 2 elements, new values have 0 elements" because it returns empty list
 df.columns = [m.group(1) + '_lang' + str(languages[m.group(2)]) for m in (re.match("^([a-zA-Z]+)\s*\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)$", col.strip().lower()) for col in df.columns) if m]
```

Desired result in case of dataframe with matching columns:

```
['name_lang1', 'name_lang2', 'name_lang3', 'Description', 'Image']
```

Is it possible to achieve this in one line ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible DataFrame constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

languages = {'ka': 1, 'en': 2, 'ru': 3}

pat = '|'.join(languages.keys())
lang = re.compile(f"(?P<prefix>[^(]+)\((?P<lang>{pat})\)", re.IGNORECASE)

df.columns = [f"{m['prefix'].lower().strip()}_lang{languages[m['lang'].lower()]}"
              if (m := lang.search(col)) else col
              for col in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
# Before
>>> df.columns.tolist()
['Name (Ka)', 'Name (En)', 'Name (Ru)', 'Description', 'Image']

# After
>>> df.columns.tolist()
['name_lang1', 'name_lang2', 'name_lang3', 'Description', 'Image']
```